# validate receipt with purchase status api return "Not Found"

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have application publish in Play Store as "Alpha Testing". After buying test product, I want to validate receipt in back-end server. I pass purchase token to php script, get access token, then the script mae https request to [this URL](https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/com.sawasdeeshop.mroaming/inapp/myProduct_sku/purchases/mypurchase_token?access_token=myac_token).

But response always return "Not Found".

Any suggestion?

Thanks